# Default screen when I focus out - iOS

Tags: swift

Always when I focus out (click on the "Home" button), Sign In page is displayed.
How to change the default picture when the app is out of focus?

Comment: Can you please explain better? I am sure no one got what you asked

Comment: 1.I'm sign in 2.Working some stuff 3.Click on Home 4.Click on Home 2x - Default page is Sign In

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add following code in `applicationWillResignActive` function in `Appdelegate`

  ```
  let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let navigationController:UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
  let rootViewController:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "You_Signin_Page") as UIViewController
  navigationController.viewControllers = [rootViewController]
  self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
  ```

**This will set "Your_Signin_Page" as your`rootViewController` everytime you press the home button**